# Assigning shortcut to "Lock to Cursor"

Tags: 3d-cursor

How can I assign shortcut to "Lock to Cursor" which is an option on the left pane in 3d viewport? I want to be able to toggle it, like enable when disabled, disable when it is enabled.

thanks

Comment: I used to want that functionality but have since found a different workflow. It might not work for your requirements but the '/' on the Keypad will toggle focus and zoom in on the selected mesh and exclude everything else.

Comment: Yeah I already use it but that is not what I am looking for.